How can I pass variables to an elixir/ecto subquery?

I have this query in ecto below:
query =
      from(tx in Treatment,
        join: ax in assoc(tx, :ax_sheet),
        join: ev in assoc(ax, :visit),
        join: evr in assoc(ev, :visit_revisions),
        where: is_nil(tx.visit_revision_id),
        where: not is_nil(ev.current_revision_id),
        select: %{
          id: tx.id,
          visit_revision_id: coalesce(ev.current_revision_id, subquery(
            from vr in VisitRevision,
            where: vr.visit_id == ^ev.id and vr.inserted_at <= ^tx.marked_at,
            order_by: [desc: vr.inserted_at],
            limit: 1,
            select: vr.id
          ))
        }
      )

I am facing an issue that where I get the following error on this line below:
 where: vr.visit_id == ^ev.id and vr.inserted_at <= ^tx.marked_at,

undefined variable ev
undefined variable tx

My question is very simple. How do I resolve this? I've read that the subquery can't retrieve what I've previously defined on the outer query, so how  can I simply just pass in the ids that I need? I'm new to elixir and am hoping this is one of those easy ones to fix. Thank you.

You can give the parent root table and parent join tables names using as: ... and access them using parent_as:.
This should work:
query =
      from(tx in Treatment,
        as: :tx,
        join: ax in assoc(tx, :ax_sheet),
        join: ev in assoc(ax, :visit),
        as: :ev,
        join: evr in assoc(ev, :visit_revisions),
        where: is_nil(tx.visit_revision_id),
        where: not is_nil(ev.current_revision_id),
        select: %{
          id: tx.id,
          visit_revision_id: coalesce(ev.current_revision_id, subquery(
            from vr in VisitRevision,
            where: vr.visit_id == parent_as(:ev).id and vr.inserted_at <= parent_as(:tx).marked_at,
            order_by: [desc: vr.inserted_at],
            limit: 1,
            select: vr.id
          ))
        }
      )

